# Scanf will only scan once in a For loop

Tags: c

scanf will only allow me to input a single number before ending the for loop, whereas I should be able to input 7, here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    float M, N=0;
    int n;
    for(n=1; n<8; n++){
        printf("Digite o peso da pessoa nro %d em kg:", n);
        scanf(" &N");
        M+=N/7;
        n=n+1;
    }
    printf("A media de peso em kg e: %f", M);
}
```

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: `scanf(" &N");` should be `scanf("%d", &N);`. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: scanf("%d", &N);

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the type. It actually should be `scanf("%f", &N);`. `if (scanf("%f", &N) != 1) return 1;` is even better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the following line:

```
scanf(" %f", &N);
```

`f` stands for your float.